# Javascript RegExp ' * ' not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a string.

```
var string="ghtykj";
var pattern = "t*y";
```

When I give new RegExp(pattern).test(string), it returns true(as expected).

```
var pattern = "t*g";
```

But this pattern also returns true.

I was expecting this pattern to return false, since t*g means t followed by zero or more number of characters ,followed by g.

If this is indeed the expected behavior , could any one correct me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to confuse regular expressions with glob: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `*` isn't a wildcard character in a regular expression, is a quantifier. It has the same meaning as the quantifier `{0,}`, i.e. specifying that the expression before it (in this case the character `t`) can occur zero or more times.

The pattern `t*g` doesn't mean t followed by zero or more number of characters, followed by g. It means zero or more of the character t, followed by one g.

The pattern `t*g` would match for example `tg` or `tttttg`, but also just `g`. So, it matches the `g` character at the beginning of the string.

To get a pattern that matches t followed by zero or more number of characters, followed by g you would use `t.*g` (or `t[\w\W]*g` to handle line breaks in the string).

Answer (score 6):

> since t*g means t followed by zero or more number of characters ,followed by g.

This is incorrect. This means 0 or more `t`, so `t` is optional.

You may be thinking instead of Globbing in terminal shells where the `*` operator would work as you expected. However Globbing `*` has different behaviour from RegEx `*`.

You want

```
var pattern = "t.*g";
```

This means, `.` is optional (0 or more instances), but there must be a `t`.

In Regular Expressions, `.` [matches almost any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).

Answer (score 3):

You should test your regex here: [regex101](http://regex101.com/), it will translate your regex into english so its easier to understand.

Comment: It sounds like a comment, but ok

Comment: I cant add a comment b.c I have low rep.

Comment: So I will help you with +10 rep .. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
var pattern = "t.*g";
```

should be right. `t*` means 0 or any number of t, which is true